# PHP - MySql Database info not storing

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, I have created a database ( MySql/PHPMyadmin) and i am trying to get user input stored to be able to call back up, however the info is not making it/ saving it to the database, everything shows up okay except this part of code:

```
$registered = mysqli_affected_rows ($dbc);

        echo $registered. "Row is affected";
```

when run gives me a display of -1 row, I believe this to be a big part of the problem as everything else seems to work okay. I am a complete beginner so could you guys tell me how the best way of debugging this is.

$dbc = `$dbc = mysqli_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) OR die("Could not Connect");`

To input the data to the db i have the following:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        $comments = $_POST ['Comments'];

        if (!empty ($comments)){

        include ('mysqldb.php');

        mysqli_query ($dbc,"INSERT INTO 'User-Comments' (Comments) VALUES ('$comments')");

        $registered = mysqli_affected_rows ($dbc);

            echo $registered. "Row is affected";

        }else {
                echo "Nothing Submitted";
            }

        }
```

Comment: How do u put data into db? Give us ur code

Comment: $dbc is the variable i created in the connection file to connect to the database

Comment: Can you echo your SQL query, copy it and paste into phpmyadmin and see what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excerpt from the documentation for function [`mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php): *-1 indicates that the query has returned an error.*

You should check the value returned by `mysqli_query()`. If it returns `FALSE` then you can get details about the reason (error message) by using function [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: Eagle-eye @kRiZ was able to identify the error without running the code. :-)

Comment: The problem was this `"INSERT INTO 'User-Comments' (Comments) VALUES ('$comments')");` it should have been `"INSERT INTO 'User-Comments' (Usercom) VALUES ('$comments')");` but yes wouldnt have noticed the backtick for a very long time after...

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
mysqli_query ($dbc,"INSERT INTO 'User-Comments' (Comments) VALUES ('$comments')");
```

should be:

```
mysqli_query ($dbc,"INSERT INTO `User-Comments` (Comments) VALUES ('$comments')");
```

Notice the change in the apostrophe character ( ` ) around your table name.

Comment: I didnt notice this syntax error untill now, it was part of the problem